# XML Entity- what's wrong with my code?

Tags: xml, entity, dtd

I'm taking a class on XML and I have to go through this book called "INeasysteps".  I'm trying to follow one of the tutorials about "Adding Comments and Entities", but when I put it in the browser I keep getting the response:

> Blockquote XML Parsing Error: undefined entity
>   Line Number 11, Column 13:
>   Blockquote

Here is my code: please let me know what I'm doing wrong.  FYI, there are no errors in the Jedit parser, but I get the error above when i put my xml code in the browser:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!-- XML in easy steps - Page 40. -->

<?xml-stylesheet 
type = "text/css" href = "history.css" ?>

<!DOCTYPE doc SYSTEM "history.dtd" >

<doc>
<para>Both &html; and &xml; are derived from &sgml; which is, in turn, a descendant of the &gml; that was developed in the 1960s by IBM. </para>
</doc>
```

Here is the history.dtd file

```
<!-- Define the root element. -->
<!-- May contain one child element called para. -->
<!ELEMENT doc (para)>

<!-- Define the child element. -->
<!-- May contain Parsed Character Data. -->

<!ELEMENT para (#PCDATA)>


<!-- Define entity values. -->
<!-- Common markup language acronyms. -->
<!ENTITY html
"HyperText Markup Language (HTML)" >
<!ENTITY xml
"eXtensible Markup Language (XML)" >
<!ENTITY sgml
"Standard Generalized Markup Language (SGML)" >
<!ENTITY gml
"Generalized Markup Language (GML)" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers won't load external entities. If you want to open the XML file in a browser and the entities to resolve properly, add the entity declarations to the internal subset (between `[` and `]` in the doctype declaration):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- XML in easy steps - Page 40. -->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href = "history.css" ?>
<!DOCTYPE doc SYSTEM "history.dtd" [
<!ENTITY html "HyperText Markup Language (HTML)" >
<!ENTITY xml "eXtensible Markup Language (XML)" >
<!ENTITY sgml "Standard Generalized Markup Language (SGML)" >
<!ENTITY gml "Generalized Markup Language (GML)" >
]>
<doc>
    <para>Both &html; and &xml; are derived from &sgml; which is, in turn, a 
        descendant of the &gml; that was developed in the 1960s by IBM. </para>
</doc>
```

Comment: got it, so I just need to add the dtd file into the xml file with the [ ] . Thank you